# Rhythmbox and Android - MTP sync issue

Tags: android, ubuntu, playlist, mtp, rhythmbox

I found problem in syncronizing Rhythmbox and my Android 4 phone.
I think that there is a problem with the MTP protocol or with Rhythmbox core.

Rhythmbox crashes during Sync!

Any suggestion?

**Detailed info:**

- Rhythmbox: v2.99.1
- OS: Ubuntu 13.10
- Mobile: LG P880 (4X-HD) with Android 4.1.2